# Finding last focusable link in subnav modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accessibility

We have four main menu items (Shirts, Pants, Footwear, Headgear) and each of them has a subnavigation menu when you click on it. For example, when clicking on Shirts, a menu opens up with more options (ABC Brand to Z Brand).

Main nav class is .mainNav

Sub nav class is .subNav

When the user tabs through the subNav and reaches the end, we want the user to be taken to the next mainNav item. For example, when the user lands on Shirts > Z Brand, and then hits tab again, we want the subNav for shirts to close and the user to be taken to Pants.

How can I find the last focusable item in the subNav so when the tab is clicked, this functionality happens?

```
<div class="mainNav">
  <a="#">Shirts</a>
  <a="#">Pants</a>
  <a="#">Footwear</a>
  <a="#">Headgear</a>
</div>

<div class="subNav-0">
  <h1>Shirts</h1>
  <a="#">ABC Brand</a>
  <a="#">Guess</a>
  <a="#">Levis</a>
  <a="#">Z Brand</a>
</div>

<div class="subNav-1">
  <h1>Pants</h1>
  <a="#">ABC Brand</a>
  <a="#">Guess</a>
  <a="#">Levis</a>
  <a="#">Z Brand</a>
</div>

<div class="subNav-2">
  <h1>Headgear</h1>
  <a="#">Big Caps</a>
  <a="#">Levis</a>
  <a="#">Pacific Hatwear</a>
  <a="#">Polo</a>
  <a="#">Stetson</a>
</div>

<div class="subNav-3">
  <h1>Footwear</h1>
  <a="#">Adidas</a>
  <a="#">Asics</a>
  <a="#">Brooks</a>
  <a="#">Converse</a>
  <a="#">New Balance</a>
  <a="#">Nike</a>
  <a="#">Puma</a>
  <a="#">Saucony</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @linnse. 
Have you tried to control the focus order using tabindex property in html?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Please **don't** use `tabindex`. That's the quickest way to mess up the tab order and is highly discouraged by most accessibility professionals. @linnse, are you able to arrange your DOM so you don't have to force a tab order? That is, when the submenu is displayed, tabbing to those elements will happen in the natural DOM order. If the next main menu item is in the DOM after the prev submenu, then the tab will work naturally without you having to do anything. The onfocus() of the main nav can hide the previous submenu.

Comment: Post a [mcve] so we aren't making guesses.

Comment: @zer00ne - Done. I should have added different brands for each category so the code is not hardcoded and based off "Z Brand", but I wanted to get the edit in before it got closed.

Comment: @slugolicious - The tab order within each subNav is fine. It's just that I need to take the user from the last subNav link to the next mainNav link.

Comment: So are you saying you are not able to change the HTML to have the order @slugolicious suggested?

Comment: @AHaworth - Yes, I have no issue with the tab order, but need to figure out how to identify when we're on the last focusable element.

Comment: I'm not clear why you need to figure out when the user is on the last focusable element - why not just let them tab through (once you've got the structure of the HTML in the right order)?

Comment: Exactly, I'm not understanding the "last element" need if the DOM is arranged correctly, although the sample code isn't quite the right order since the subnav is after the main nav.

Comment: For some reason, I can't select the last focusable element when I use the following: $('.subNav:starts-with(subNav) a:last');

Comment: @linnse Please read [ask], and how to post your code as a [mcve]  (include JavaScript/jQuery). When you're ready to post your code
⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪

Answer (score 2):

The comments section was getting full so I wanted to post some code here.  The sample code posted in the OP does not have each subnav directly after each main nav element so the tabbing order won't be handled properly by the browser.

If the code were changed to this, it would help:

```
<div class="mainNav">
  <a="#">Shirts</a>
    <div class="subNav-0">
      <h1>Shirts</h1>
      <a="#">ABC Brand</a>
      <a="#">Guess</a>
      <a="#">Levis</a>
      <a="#">Z Brand</a>
    </div>
  <a="#">Pants</a>
    <div class="subNav-1">
      <h1>Pants</h1>
      <a="#">ABC Brand</a>
      <a="#">Guess</a>
      <a="#">Levis</a>
      <a="#">Z Brand</a>
    </div>
  <a="#">Footwear</a>
    <div class="subNav-3">
      <h1>Footwear</h1>
      <a="#">Adidas</a>
      <a="#">Asics</a>
      <a="#">Brooks</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each subnav should have `display:none` until the main nav is selected to open it. When it has `display:none`, it's not in the tab order. When it has `display:block`, it'll be inserted into the tab order by the browser without you having to do anything.

There are other accessibility considerations that weren't mentioned in the OP, such as each main nav element should have [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) so that the screen reader will know it's a collapsed section that can be opened.

Comment: Thanks for posting. After tabbing away from the very last link in the modal, I need to 1) close the modal, and 2) move focus to the next main nav item. For example, once someone clicks away from Pants > Z Brand, the Pants modal closes and the user is tabbed to "Footwear".

Comment: @linnse you haven't shown us any Javascript. What you need to do on one of those main items being 'tabbed to' is close all the subnavs.

Comment: Pretty easy to have an onfocus() on an element and have it close the submenu, as I mentioned in one of my original comments.